# 502 Bad Gateway on Elastic Beanstalk application with HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy an Elastic Beanstalk application with HTTPS, but I keep receiving a 502 error from my HTTPS endpoint. I can access the HTTP endpoint just fine, and the site seems to work as expected. I only see this error for HTTPS. I'm not exactly sure where to look to find the error, but I didn't see anything that seemed relevant in any of the logs on the EC2 instance. Could this be a problem with my SSL certificate? I'm currently using a self-signed certificate for testing. Here's the relevant portion of the CloudFormation template I'm using to create the resources:

```
Resources:

  # VPC and Subnets
  Vpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      InstanceTenancy: default
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "ClimbAssistVpc${ResourceNameSuffix}"
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  VpcGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  SubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-west-2a
      CidrBlock: 10.0.0.0/17
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  SubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-west-2b
      CidrBlock: 10.0.128.0/18
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  SubnetC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-west-2c
      CidrBlock: 10.0.192.0/18
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: 'Security group for Climb Assist Elastic Beanstalk application'
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - CidrIp: '0.0.0.0/0'
        IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
      - CidrIp: '0.0.0.0/0'
        IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
      SecurityGroupEgress:
      - CidrIp: '0.0.0.0/0'
        IpProtocol: -1 # all protocols
        ToPort: 0
        FromPort: 65535
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref Vpc
  Route:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VpcGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
  SubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetB
  SubnetCRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetC

  # Elastic Beanstalk environments
  EBApplication:
    Description: The AWS Elastic Beanstalk application, which is a container used to deploy the correct application configuration.
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Sub '${ProjectId}app${ResourceNameSuffix}'
      Description: The name of the AWS Elastic Beanstalk application to be created for this project.
  EBApplicationVersion:
    Description: The version of the AWS Elastic Beanstalk application to be created for this project.
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref 'EBApplication'
      Description: The application version number.
      SourceBundle: 'target/ROOT'
  EBConfigurationTemplate:
    Description: The AWS Elastic Beanstalk configuration template to be created for this project, which defines configuration settings used to deploy different versions of an application.
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ConfigurationTemplate
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref 'EBApplication'
      Description: The name of the sample configuration template.
      OptionSettings:
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
        OptionName: EnvironmentType
        Value: LoadBalanced
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
        OptionName: ServiceRole
        Value: !Ref 'EBTrustRole'
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system
        OptionName: SystemType
        Value: enhanced
      SolutionStackName: !Ref 'SolutionStackName'
  EBEnvironment:
    Description: The AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployment group where the application is deployed, which is made up of the Amazon EC2 Linux instances launched for this project.
    Type: AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref 'EBApplication'
      EnvironmentName: !Ref 'EBApplication'
      CNAMEPrefix:
        Fn::Sub: "${ProjectId}${ResourceNameSuffix}"
      Description: The application to be deployed to the environment.
      TemplateName: !Ref 'EBConfigurationTemplate'
      VersionLabel: !Ref 'EBApplicationVersion'
      OptionSettings:
      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
        OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
        Value: !Ref 'EBInstanceProfile'
      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
        OptionName: InstanceType
        Value: !Ref 'InstanceType'
      - Namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
        OptionName: EC2KeyName
        Value: !Ref 'KeyPairName'
      - Namespace: aws:ec2:vpc
        OptionName: VPCId
        Value: !Ref Vpc
      - Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc'
        OptionName: Subnets
        Value:
          Fn::Join:
          - ','
          - - !Ref SubnetA
            - !Ref SubnetB
            - !Ref SubnetC
      - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
        OptionName: SecurityGroups
        Value: !Ref SecurityGroup
      - Namespace: 'aws:ec2:vpc'
        OptionName: AssociatePublicIpAddress
        Value: 'true'
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
        OptionName: LoadBalancerType
        Value: application
      - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listener:443
        OptionName: DefaultProcess
        Value: https
      - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listener:443
        OptionName: ListenerEnabled
        Value: 'true'
      - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listener:443
        OptionName: Protocol
        Value: HTTPS
      - Namespace: aws:elbv2:listener:443
        OptionName: SSLCertificateArns
        Value: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:172776452117:certificate/724f70c2-01bd-415d-adbc-a5167d4a6fad
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:https
        OptionName: Port
        Value: '443'
      - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:https
        OptionName: Protocol
        Value: HTTPS
```

I'm still new to Elastic Beanstalk and EC2 so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: do you map port 443 on balancer to port 80 on instance?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure, and I don't really know how to check that. Do you know how I can check?

Comment: console -> elasticbeanstalk -> your app -> load balancer

Comment: can you try with sameple node_v1.zip first ? then you can deploy your code ?

Comment: @NeverBe that looks like that fixed the error. With this new configuration, this means that when I connect to the load balancer, I'm connecting with HTTPS, but when the load balancer routes it to the the instance, it's using HTTP, right? What if I want to use HTTPS for both connections?

Comment: Yes it terminates SSL on balancer side and sends unencrypted traffic to the instances. What do you mean "both connections"?

Comment: I mean, how can I send encrypted traffic from the load balancer to the instance? I don't want my traffic to ever be unencrypted. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: you need to redirect it from 80 -> 443 using nginx on the instance's side or on rails's app side. just google it

Comment: Alright I'll try that - thank you!

Comment: @NeverBe i have the exactly same problem described above by Kyle but with aws eb single instance, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this thanks to @NeverBe. I was mapping the HTTPS listener on port 443 of the load balancer to port 443 on the instance. Instead, I needed to route port 443 on the load balancer to port 80 on the instance.

Comment: You are right. The `processes` default `Port` for me is `80`.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem with my NodeJs and ExpressJs backend microservices. Discovered this when I tried to access the endpoint. I had my code updated in Elastic Beanstalk by linking it with AWS CodeBuild and GitHub. I noticed that the deploy stage worked fine without any errors. After a bit of investigation found out that the command to run my server in the instance was missing, that is `npm start` or `node <main_server_file_name>.js`. And everything was up and working in secounds. You can update this command in `Configuration > Software > Command` inside the Environment.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after reading @Kyle Cooley's post I was able to realize my target group was set to Http instead of Https. 502 could mean many things, in my case it was trying to use HTTP protocol to connect when the endpoint required HTTPs instead.